# Let $(X, d)$ be a separable metric space. Then the space of all real-valued bounded uniformly continuous functions on $X$ is separable

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, uniform-continuity, separable-spaces

It's well-known that

- [Theorem 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4567286/if-e-is-compact-then-mathcal-c-b-e-is-separable) A metric space is compact IFF its space of bounded, continuous, real-valued functions is separable in the uniform topology.

I would like to prove its complementary result, i.e.,

> **Theorem 2** Let $(X, d)$ be a separable metric space. Then the space of all real-valued bounded uniformly continuous functions on $X$ is separable.

Could you have a check on below proof?

---

**My attempt** We need the following lemmas, i.e.,

- *[Lemma 1:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4436642/let-x-d-be-a-separable-metric-space-there-exists-a-compact-metric-space)* If $X$ is separable, then there exists a compact metric space $Y$ and a map $T: X \to Y$ such that $T$ is a homeomorphism from $X$ onto $T(X)$.
- **Lemma 2** Suppose $Y$ and $Z$ are metric spaces, and $Z$ is complete. Also suppose $X$ is a dense subset of $Y$, and $f: X \rightarrow Z$ is uniformly continuous. Then $f$ has a uniquely determined extension $\bar{f}: Y \rightarrow Z$ given by
  $$
  \bar{f}(y)=\lim _{\substack{x \rightarrow y \\ x \in X}} f(x) \quad \text { for } y \in Y,
  $$
  and $\bar{f}$ is also uniformly continuous. [*Theorem 2.1* at page 10 of Amann/Escher's *Analysis III*]
- [Lemma 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3411109/a-continuous-function-on-a-compact-metric-space-is-uniformly-continuous) Let $f:X \to Y$ be continuous and $X,Y$ be metric spaces where $X$ is compact. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

By **Lemma 1**, there is a metric $d'$ on $X$ such that $d,d'$ induce the same topology and $d'$ is totally bounded. Let $X_1$ be the completion of $X$ w.r.t. $d'$. Then $(X_1, d')$ is compact.

By **Theorem 1**, the space $\mathcal C_b(X_1)$ of all real-valued bounded continuous functions on $X_1$ is separable. Let $\mathcal{UC}_b (X)$ be the space of all real-valued bounded uniformly continuous functions on $X$.

By **Lemma 3**, $\mathcal{UC}_b (X_1) = \mathcal{C}_b (X_1)$. By **Lemma 2**, $\mathcal{UC}_b (X)$ can be embedded isometrically into $\mathcal{UC}_b (X_1)$. This completes the proof.

---

**Update:** It seems I made a fatal mistake. It should be

> "$\mathcal{UC}_b (X, d')$ can be embedded isometrically into $\mathcal{UC}_b (X_1)$"

instead of

> "$\mathcal{UC}_b (X)$ can be embedded isometrically into $\mathcal{UC}_b (X_1)$".

Of course, $\mathcal{UC}_b (X, d') \neq \mathcal{UC}_b (X, d)$.

Comment: I have not read your proof. But "Theorem 2" is false. Suppose $X$ is the closed unit ball in the real Banach space $\ell_1. $ Then  the space of real, bounded, uniformly continuous functions on $X$ has a non-separable subspace consisting of the closed unit ball of $\ell_{\infty}$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thank you so much for your counter-example. Could you post it as an answer?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Is $\{f_{\restriction X} : f \in B\}$ with $B$ the closed unit ball of $\ell_{\infty}$ the non-separable subspace you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, to be precise about it, the members of the subspace are restrictions to the domain $X$ of the members of the closed unit ball of $\ell_{\infty}.$

Comment: BTW if Theorem 2 were true then by Theorem 1 every separable metric space would be compact, which is absurd. A more elementary counter-example: $X=\Bbb R$ and $d(x,y)=|x-y|.$ For $n\in \Bbb Z$ let $f_n(x)=(x-2n-1)^2(x-2n+1)^2$ if $x\in [2n-1,2n+1]$ and let $f_n(x)=0$ if $x\in\Bbb R\setminus [2n-1,2n+1].$  Now for any $S\subseteq \Bbb Z$ let $f^S(x)=f_n(x)$ if $n\in S$ and $x\in  [2n-1,2n+1],$ otherwise $f^S(x)=0.$  If $S,T$ are unequal subsets of $\Bbb Z$ and $n\in S\Delta T$ then $\{f^S(2n),f^T(2n)\}}=$ $\{0,1\}$.